# How can I configure authorization in keycloak based on last login

Tags: authorization, keycloak, policy, claims

There are varying levels of data that a given user may have access to. I want to configure an endpoint so that last time the user supplied their credentials defines the level of authorization they have.

e.g.:

- > 1 hour = level 1
- < 1 hour > 10 minutes = level 2
- < 10 minutes = level 3

I looked at the time-based policy but that does not appear to do what I want. I prefer to leverage keycloak to do this rather than hack up the client to derive these levels itself. The user should be able to request a resource, and the credentials they access that resource with define presumably the access-level (role does not appear to be appropriate for this case), which defines what they have permission to read vs. what would be empty. I looked at the custom authenticator, but that seems only for authentication as opposed to authorization. Like a dynamic time-based policy.

Is this feasible via keycloak? And is it a server feature? How can I configure something that changes with time?

Answer (score 0):

This purely seems like a Server feature and you've to program it internally based on the keycloak access token expiration time.

Keycloak's Time based policy covers the authorization of a user under certain period of time (A user can access app/api/webpage only in the period of time for which time based policy has been implemented, a user accessing the feature before or after time-based policy's mentioned time can not access it). it doesn't cover the hierarchical authorization level that you require.

The only solution i can find to your problem is **JavaScript-Based Policy** , though you still need to define the rules programmatically as defined in documentation:

> You can use this type of policy to define conditions for your permissions using JavaScript. It is one of the rule-based policy types supported by Keycloak, and provides flexibility to write any policy based on the Evaluation API.

Here you can read in details regarding Javascript-based policies:
https://wjw465150.gitbooks.io/keycloak-documentation/content/authorization_services/topics/policy/js-policy.html

So, keycloak doesn't provide any solution for your problem out of the box, you've to do it programmatically inside your Server or through Javascript-based policies